# Redis Data type for storing same values with different scores

Tags: redis

Scenario is that : when I run a test, if it fails then store timestamp and fail value in redis and Get last three timestamps and values for same test if all are fail then send an Email to project head.

I was thinking off adding scores in sorted zset in redis:

```
zadd Health:TestName timestamp1 "Fail"
zadd Health:TestName timestamp2 "Success"
zadd Health:TestName timestamp3 "Fail"
zadd Health:TestName timestamp4 "Fail"
zadd Health:TestName timestamp5 "Fail"
```

So if I run the Test `TestName` now and if it fails, `I get last three timestamps and values and check if all are Fail`. If all are Fail then send an Email. But Zadd doesn't allow me to add same value for different scores. What could be the other way to store this data.

Note. I have to use `redis` only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "trick" here is to make the members unique, and the simplest way is to concatenate the result and the timestamp, i.e.:

```
zadd Health:TestName timestamp1 "Fail:timestamp1"
zadd Health:TestName timestamp2 "Success:timestamp2"
zadd Health:TestName timestamp3 "Fail:timestamp3"
zadd Health:TestName timestamp4 "Fail:timestamp4"
zadd Health:TestName timestamp5 "Fail:timestamp5"
```

Then, when fetching the members, simply ignore the suffix.

Tip: to save RAM, switch to using short-as-possible-strings. In your case, instead of "Fail" and "Success" just use 0 and 1 (or "F" and "S"...), thus saving 9 bytes for each member. You can also drop the colon (":") when concatenating for an extra saved byte, i.e. `Ftimestamp1`, `Stimestamp2` and so forth.